# Función que tome una variable (de cualquier tipo) y determine si dicha variable contiene un número

Tags: funciones, variables, haskell

Del sitio stackoverflow en inglés extraje esta función que verifica si una cadena se trata de un número.

```
import Data.Char

esNumerico :: String -> Bool
esNumerico ""  = False
esNumerico "." = False
esNumerico xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

¿Hay alguna forma de modificar la función de modo que en lugar de que verifique que una cadena es un número, pueda hacerlo para que verifique una variable de cualquier tipo?

Pruebo con esto:

```
import Data.Char

esNumerico :: Eq a => a -> Bool
esNumerico ""  = False
esNumerico "." = False
esNumerico xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

Comment: Estás preguntando si hay forma de saber si una variable numérica es un número, lo que es bastante obvio. Si la función esperaba un número y le pasas otra cosa, simplemente no compilará. Puedes hacer una función genérica con restricciones de tipo usando `Num` (o también `Integral`, `Fractional`, `Rational`, ...), pero no es exáctamente lo que estás buscando. Puede que lo que busques se pueda hacer con `Data.Typeable`, pero complica bastante las cosas.

Comment: ¿Y como sería eso?

Comment: Me recomendaron esto `isNumeric :: Show a => a -> Bool` pero tira error más abajo en la función.

Answer (score 0):

Con la restricción `Show a` lo que indicas es que se puede convertir en una cadena de texto, con lo que puedes aplicar el mismo código que pones al principio:

```hs
import Data.Char (isDigit)

esCadenaNumerica :: String -> Bool
esCadenaNumerica ""  = False   
esCadenaNumerica "." = False
esCadenaNumerica xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False

esNumerico :: Show a => a -> Bool
esNumerico x = esCadenaNumerica (show x)
```

Funcionamiento:

```hs
esNumerico 12  -- True
esNumerico 4.57  -- True
esNumerico 1e+12 -- False
esNumerico "12" -- False
```

Se puede ver que falla porque la función `esCadenaNumerica` se deja opciones como un número real representado como `1e12`. También falla si el número está ya como cadena (`show "12"` da como resultado `"\"12\""`). Seguramente dé más fallos, por lo que no es una solución *"typesafe"*.

Como he dicho en el comentario, el sistema de tipos en haskell es *estático*, por lo que se conocen todos los tipos de datos antes de la ejecución del programa. Sabemos si una variable es un número desde el comienzo y no va a cambiar durante todo el programa.

Así pues, podemos hacer que nuestra función sólo admita números restringiendo el tipo del argumento para que sea de la clase `Num`:

```hs
esNumerico :: Num a => a -> Bool
esNumerico _ = True
```

Funcionamiento:

```hs
esNumerico 12  -- True
esNumerico 4.57  -- True
esNumerico 1e+12 -- True
esNumerico "12" -- ### Error
```

El uso de `Typeable` es demasiado complicado y extenso para explicar aquí. Lo mejor es consultar la serie de artículos sobre el tema de [Toan Nguyen](https://medium.com/@hgiasac/typeable-a-long-journey-to-type-safe-dynamic-type-representation-9070eac2cf8b) si le interesa a alguien.

Comment: Si yo esto lo aplico a la función mcd compila pero si pongo argumentos erróneos Haskell tira error en lugar de mostrar el mensaje por defecto.

Comment: `mcd` no tiene porqué comprobar que sus argumentos son otra cosa que enteros, para eso está el compilador. Explica mejor qué quieres conseguir pasando argumentos erróneos a mcd.

Comment: No me estás entendiendo. La función por si sola funciona, pero apicada a otra función no funciona correctamente, no ejecuta la opción por defecto sino tira error Haskell. Pásate por esta nueva pregunta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/603906/funci%c3%b3n-esnumerico-con-error-al-llamarlo-desde-otras-funciones) así me entiendes un poco mejor.

Comment: Insisto en que con haskell nunca podrás pasar argumentos a `mcd` que no sean enteros. Es parte del diseño del lenguaje, la seguridad de tipos (_typesafe_). Cuando dices que te da error, date cuenta que es un error de compilación, no de ejecución.

Comment: Bueno, esta bien, pero ¿viste el enlace que te dejé?

Comment: Sí, y el comentario de otro compañero que te insiste en lo mismo.