# Función esNumerico con error al llamarla desde otras funciones

Tags: funciones, haskell

Tengo esta función extraída del sitio stackoverflow en inglés que verifica si una cadena se trata de un número.

```
import Data.Char

esCadenaNumerica :: String -> Bool
esCadenaNumerica ""  = False
esCadenaNumerica "." = False
esCadenaNumerica xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

Un usuario me respondió una función que tome una variable de cualquier tipo y evalúe si esta es un número

```
esNumerico :: Show a => a -> Bool
esNumerico x = esCadenaNumerica (show x)
```

Ahora bien, de forma independiente funciona correctamente pero cuando uso esta función en, por ejemplo, la función propia `mcd`, en el caso de que el usuario ingrese un dato erróneo, en lugar de ir la función por defecto, Haskell tira error.

Ejemplo:

```
mcd :: (Int,Int) -> Int 
mcd (x,y) = if esNumerico (x) && esNumerico (y) then
             if y == 0 then
                x                     -- paso base
             else
                mcd (y, x `mod` y)    -- paso inductivo
            else
               error "Los argumentos deben ser números"
```

**Ejemplo de uso**

```
mcd (10,25)
```

Resultado esperado y obtenido:

```
5
```

Segundo caso:

```
mcd (4,"10")
```

Resultado esperado:

```
Error: Los argumentos deben ser números
```

Resultado obtenido:

```
<interactive>:15:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the expression: "10"
      In the first argument of ‘mcd’, namely ‘(4, "10")’
      In the expression: mcd (4, "10")
```

Comment: Ya no recuerdo mucho de Haskell, pero si defines la función mcd como (Int, Int) e intentas evaluar (4, "10") parece normal que te dé ese error. No tiene nada que ver con la función esNumerico.